# UINavigationBar Images - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

How can I add an image to a UINavigationBar that is a UIButton? For example, take a look at the Safari app. It has some nice buttons on the bottom UINavigationBar. I'd like to put a Share button on a UINavigationBar. Does anyone know how to do this? And does anyone know where I can get a "Share" button? For instance, the type of "Share" button that pulls up an email and emails someone something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom bar is a [`UIToolbar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the buttons are instance of [`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can use the `initWithImage:style:target:action:` initializer for your purpose.

Comment: and then how do I add the UIBarButtonItem to the UIToolbar

Comment: Using `setItems:animated:`. You can't add them one by one. Build an array of items that you want on your toolbar and add them using that method.

Comment: do you know where I can find a "share" image?

Comment: There is no framework provided icon for this. You will have to look at third party icon sets. As for the email part, you can look at [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).